# custom zbuffer in a 2d game / reading pixels from a frame buffer in a fragment shader (glsl)

Tags: opengl, glsl, depth-buffer, 2d-games

I'm writing a 2D (actually 2.5D) Isometric Game in OpenGL. 
To circumvent sorting the tiles which can be quite complicated in some cases i'm trying to simulate some kind of depth buffer. For every tile i have two images, one with the color information and one with the depth information.

Image1: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/91457585/depth_buffer_test.png

As a first approach I created these pictures. The idea is to draw them on top of each other and use a shader to do the depth test. In this case it doesn't make much sense i know, however is just a first approach to see if it's technically possible.

So now to my problem!

Below you see the code of the shader. It is supposed to compare the depth information of the framebuffer with the one of the object. 
However it does not seem to work and now i read somewhere that this is just not possible the way i did.

Listing:

```
#version 130
uniform sampler2D colorMap;
uniform sampler2D zMap;  
uniform float level;

out vec4 gs_FragColor[ 2 ];

void main(void) { 
    float z = texture2D( zMap, gl_TexCoord[0].st ).r; 
    if ( z > gs_FragColor[ 1 ].r ){
      gs_FragColor[ 1 ] = vec4( z, 0, 0, 1 );
      gs_FragColor[ 0 ] = texture2D( colorMap, gl_TexCoord[0].st ).rgba;
    }
}
```

So is there any better method to simulate a depth buffer? Maybe by writing to a real depth buffer?

Answer (score 0):

There are (complicated and possibly very slow) ways to simulate a depth buffer, but I don't see why you should need something like that. I would recommend using the regular OpenGL depth test: For each fragment of your tile, you look up the corresponding depth value in your texture and write it to `gl_FragDepth`. If you have depth test enabled in your host code (`glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST)`), OpenGL will do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can simulate Z buffer but it will be too slow because you needed to draw back to it which will lead to many passes (1. pass for each overlapping block of tiles), better and much faster solution is to do it without OpenGL, directly to Canvas and store Screen and Z -buffers as DIB bitmaps or 1D/2D array. but if you have a lot of tiles to draw to big resolutions it will be slow too (but still faster than OpenGL implementation of this).
2. you use your tile depth maps as depth texture and render normaly with Depth test ON - it is fastest simplest and nicest solution for your problem. (z value from texture is added to actual z coord value of each fragment so you specify tile layer by actual vertex coords only)

strongly recommending second choice...